# After I create a multi-level list, why does Word then select Numbering?

Tags: microsoft-word

Please see below. In screenshot 2, why does Word select "Numbering", not "Multilevel List" that I originally clicked?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no explanation - that's the way it works, and that's the way it always worked.
It's just the way that the Ribbon in Word was (badly) programmed.

I have looked for YouTube videos for various Word versions, and it was always
like that since the Ribbon user interface was introduced by Microsoft in
Microsoft Office 2007.

You may report the problem to Microsoft using the Feedback Hub, but I think the
chances are slim that this will be corrected.

You may watch these YouTube videos:

- [Make, Format and Auto-number Multi level list in Microsoft Word 2013-2016 Tips and Tricks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ytIcbwIpDrs)
  (from 2016)
- [How to create a "Multi-Level List" in Microsoft Word 2007,2010 and 2013](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qPqLUxAUvXM)
  (from 2013)

Answer (score 1):

I think having the multi-level list as it's own button was (and continues to be) a poor design choice as it causes confusion all the time.  In my experience, it will never look like it's selected. It only provides easy access to the multi-level list settings so you have to think of it as related to the other two, not as it's own button.  This takes some getting used to since it's counter to the way the rest of the ribbon works. Even after using Word for over two decades now, I forget this if I haven't used Word in a while and will expect it to come on once I add a second level. When it doesn't I then remember this reason why.

The main reason Microsoft Word selects *Numbering* after you have created your multi-level list is because you used a number and it will always go to the type of list being used, bullets or numbers.

If you instead use varying bullet types for your different levels, it will show the bullets button as the selected format.
[Screenshot of bulleted list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKzFN.jpg)

I learned this years ago from Microsoft's Technet which is no longer a thing, so I cannot provide a link for reference.

As a bonus tip if you want to be able to use your multi-level list format in other parts of the document you have to save it in it's own style then apply that style later. Otherwise the next list will take on what is set in the default *list paragraph* style.